# How to create templates based in components in Angular 2+?

Tags: angular

I can't find it on google. I need something like...

```
 <my-custom-component><p>Hello World !</p></my-custom-component>
```

and on the myCustomComponent.component.html, I'd like to see something like:

```
<div>
  <p>Hello World !</p>
</div>
```

In other words: I need to encapsulate html tags inside my own custom component. How to do it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ng-content` is your guy :

```html
<my-custom-component><p>Hello World !</p></my-custom-component>
```

**my-custom-component.html**

```html
<div>
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
```

(Nothing more to do)